# ¿Cómo asignar una tecla a una función en C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, formularios

Quiero hacer un 'form' tipo 'Splash' (hasta ahí todo bien).

Pero cuando asigno la tecla escape a `Close();` este no hace absolutamente nada, ya intenté crear un botón y agregar `Close();` y en las propiedades del 'form' asignarle ese botón la tecla de cancelacion pero nada.

```
private void NuevaOrdenManual_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: No hay mas eventos que eviten el cierre? probaste con this.close();?

Comment: Donde estas captando el keydown?

Comment: @gbianchi si probe con this.Close() pero el mismo visual me dice que es innecesario, con close() es igual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu función esta bien, pero tu formulario tiene la propiedad KeyPreview en **true**?

Esta propiedad determina si los eventos de teclado para los controles del formulario se registran junto con el formulario.

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_Form_KeyPreview

Saludos!